# When I try adding something to the project, Visual Studio just crashes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I think I found a reproducible bug in visual studio. When I try adding "TestControl" to the project, visual studio just crashes.

Maybe it's my fault, and I'm doing something wrong. All I do is BUILD, and add the control to the form:

[image: VSCrash]

Here's the project (11kb): https://www.dropbox.com/s/dk62j347zmwbll8/VisualStudioCrash.zip

I haven't included any binary files. If you want to test it, build it and add "TestControl" to the form. If you somehow manage, click on the control and see if it crashes then.

Comment: "...And it still crashes" have you successfully rebuilt the project after making the correction?  If not, Visual Studio may still be using the old version of the assembly.

Comment: @Joe Yup, that was it. I'm going to remove the edit because it was a mistake from my end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cause is fairly obvious:

```
public string Description
{
    get
    {
        return Description;
    }
    set
    {
        // lblDescription.Text = value;
    }
}
```

You're making a recursive call to the get accessor for the `Description` property. Visual Studio is going into an infinite loop when you place the control on the designer.

Comment: Doesn't this throw a stack overflow eventually? Anyway it's easily done :) - sometimes causes a 'hard to see' bug as the accessor is only executed when something tries to evaluate the property - even the debugger can cause it to crash. Keep your eyes peeled!

Comment: @Charleh I guess Visual Studio isn't quite as robust as it should be. I know from experience that it will gracefully handle exceptions that occur in a control's constructor, or exceptions that occur while painting the control... but I guess it doesn't do so while reading properties.

Comment: I'll have a look, but my VS2010 seems to have frozen just loading the project :D ahh gotta love VS2010

Comment: @David Are you sure you recompiled after making your changes? I just added a label as with your edit and could not replicate the problem; the control was added successfully to the form.

Comment: @BradleySmith Whoops, didn't notice the "Build Failed". It worked, thanks!

Comment: Works for me, but then again lblDescription was missing from mine (not sure why) so I just added a new label to the UC and dropped it onto the main form

Comment: Haha yeah don't forget to build before using usercontrols from the toolbox :)

Comment: @Charleh I find that it's a good idea to place custom controls in a separate project to the one that consumes them; otherwise, you can end up with some really obtuse errors (like this one, for example).

Comment: And don't forget really long build times...!

Comment: @Charleh That's what I'm doing, not like I have a choice lol, because there are literally thousands of GUI components in this project, it takes whole minutes to build. So I'm splitting it into separate user controls and trying them out in different projects for now.